# Is it possible to do a loop based on a if statement?

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

I'm trying to have my code loop if the user clicks no after entering their input.

```
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

    public class Sizer extends WindowAdapter 
    {
            public static void main (String[]args){


            JFrame m = new JFrame();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(m,"Ok To set the window size you are going to type in the number for each value REMEMBER THE SIZE IS IN PIXELS");


            String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Height (suggested under 1080 and above 300)");
            int Height= Integer.parseInt( input1);
```

After this input I have to confirm if this user entered it in correctly if they click yes it keeps going if they click no it exits I want it to have the user type it in again how would I do this?

```
        int a1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(m,"Are you sure that this is the correct Height"+ Height);
        if (a1==JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
        if (a1==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){

        }

        String input2= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Width (suggested under 1920 and above 300)");
        int Width = Integer.parseInt( input2);




        JFrame frame = new JFrame();                    
        Slop comp = new Slop();
        frame.add(comp);
        frame.setSize(Height,Width);
        frame.setTitle("Slop of a Line");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
                }   
        }
}
```

`

Comment: Yes! Look up `while(..) { }` and `do { .. } while(..);` loops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a do...while loop, and clear the height if the user clicks "no"

```
public class Sizer extends WindowAdapter 
{
    public static void main (String[]args){

        JFrame m = new JFrame();
        int height = 0;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(m,"Ok To set the window size you are going to type in the number for each value REMEMBER THE SIZE IS IN PIXELS");

        do {
            String input1= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Height (suggested under 1080 and above 300)");
            height= Integer.parseInt(input1);
            int a1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(m,"Are you sure that this is the correct Height "+ height);

             if (a1==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION){
                height = 0;
            }

        } while (height==0)
    }

}
```

This assumes height must be > 0. If height can be 0, use -1 as the initial and reset values instead.

EDIT:

@Nicholas K's answer shows you don't actually need that if statement, instead just finish the while loop like so:

```
            a1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(m,"Are you sure that this is the correct Height "+ height);

        } while (a1==JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)
```

To do so though, you need to initialize a1 at the beginning of the method.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
    int a1 = 0;
    do { 
      // Read input till user says 'yes
      a1 = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(m, "Are you sure that this is the correct Height "+ Height);
    } while (a1 == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION);
```

So the loop continues to run until the user enters the value `JOptionPane.NO_OPTION`